# Chrome Extension: content script is unable to load local HTML file into iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-script

There is a content script defined in manifest.json. 
The content script is doing a simple task.
It adds a **iframe** into page and trying to open a **local HTML** file into it.

The problem is:

```
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://www.xyz.com/");   //working correctly.
```

**BUT**

```
ifrm.setAttribute("src", chrome.extension.getURL("view/abc.html")); //Not working
```

The iframe is not opening a **local HTML file**.

Any suggestion...

Comment: If I remember right, you need to set something with the `web_accessible_resources`.

Comment: Thanks thats works.. please do answer below.. i'll vote... :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the file in the [`web_accessible_resources`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html) and it is case sensitive.